Search stored procedure for database driven page
My input form page is database driven. For this I have created 3 tables Page, PageSection and PageSectionDetail.
Page has names of table, PageSection lists the section of each page and PageSectionDetail lists control and its properties in each section

I have a table called ItemAttributes that saves all the data from input form. Thing to note here is that text field and dropdown in input form creates single entry in ItemAttribute table, also, there are multiselect dropdown in the form that creates multiple entries in ItemAttribute. Each entry form has an unique identifier called ItemID.
Now I have created a search screen like this

From my react frontend, I pass an array of ControlID and ControlValue to my API, based on the selection of control in the search page. Now I don't know how to pass the array to a stored procedure and get the search result and display the result as shown in second screenshot.
The only progress I have made is a simple select and I am drawing a blank as to how to proceed.
SELECT 
    ia.ID, ia.ItemID, ia.ControlID, psd.ControlName, ia.ControlValue
FROM  
    ItemAttributes AS ia 
INNER JOIN
    PageSectionDetail AS psd ON ia.ControlID = psd.ControlID 
INNER JOIN
    PageSection AS ps ON ia.SectionID = ps.SectionID 
INNER JOIN
    Page AS p ON ps.PageID = p.PageID
WHERE 
    (p.PageName = N'NewItemEntry') 
    AND (ps.SectionID IN (2, 7))

How do I put the array in where clause and I know I will have to use pivot to show each ControlName as column header. But the problem is that for multiple entries I want them under same heading with values comma separated. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
I am putting the image of how the data looks for the above select


You could create a SQL table type to pass in the array, or pass in a comma delimited string and parse it out in your SQL SP.

@Brad I have no clue what you are talking about. I am mostly a front and middle tier developer. this is my first foray into the complex stored proc. Can you add little more detail or example

If you do some searching you will find plenty of examples
